# Validating Human Height using javascript

Tags: jquery, validation, textbox

I require have a textbox to enter a human height. I require to do this using jquery. Is there a plugin or code sample that I can use to, to perform the validation. Can someone please help me to validate the textbox using jquery.

Comment: Get the textbox's `.val()`, check if it's within acceptable range (metric or imperial? Note also that the range is [surprisingly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shortest_people) [wide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_people)), done. Which part is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to use regex:

```
var height = '4\'3"'; //$('selector-to-input').val()
if (/^[0-9]+\' ?[0-9]+\"$/.match(height)) {
    //do something
}
```

That's not the greatest regex but it will check anything like 9' 5" or 5'7" or 5'11".

For more regex stuff check out: [Regex Info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

**Edit:** Better regex may be something like

```
/^[0-9]+ ?(\'|ft|cm|meters|feet|in|inches|\")?( *[1-9]+ ?(\"|inches|in|cm)?)?$/
```

You'll have to test it, on lunch break and need to get back to work.

Comment: Useful for "imperial" measures, but will fail on `6'` (never have I ever seen `6' 0"`), on `6 ft`, `72"`, or `182 cm`.

Comment: @Piskvor: True /^[0-9]+\'( ?[0-9]+\")?$/ would solve the 6'. Again not the best regex for it, just quickly wrote it up but I'm sure there are better already thought out ones out there.

Comment: Probably. The use of two different measurement units is sort of problematic, esp. as there are two different ways to abbreviate them. Perhaps two text boxes `[   6  ] ft [   1  ] in` might be less confusing to the users, and easier to parse, but that's slightly out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Do two text boxes: one for feet, one for inches.  Then put them both into the same units.

like:

```
var person_height = $(feet).val()*12 + $(inches).val();
```

This is so they only input numbers -- no characters.

Or, if you're in Europe or wherever, just ONE text box for **meters**.  (1.5 meters)

Oh, metric system.  Soon.